# My android app crashes on startup using apk without adding any code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, apk

my app crashes on startup using apk because i have issues with my laptop so i cannot use the emulator.

The application crashes without even adding any code to it is it a problem with the build process or with android studio installation or what.

2018-09-26 18:46:06.001 1672-1752/? E/MFI-Conn:  (          mdfx_conn_conn,   76) mdfx_conn_conn(): the MFI connection fails!!
2018-09-26 18:46:06.001 1672-1752/? E/MFI-Conn:  (   mdfx_conn_init_legacy,  363) mdfx_conn_init_legacy(): mdfx_conn_conn() error!!
2018-09-26 18:46:06.001 1672-1752/? E/MFI-RDS:  (       rds_mal_conn_init,  819) [RDS][rds_mal_conn_init] mdfx_conn_init_legacy gets NULLLLLLL!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you post the error of the logcat please? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Connect your phone and run, check if it's crashing in debug Mode, if it crashes, check the logs in Android studio.

Comment: android studio doesnt find my device therefore there isnt any logcat. i can only test the app using the apk

Comment: We have neither the code not the crash log. What can we say? Have you read about [enabling the developer mode and USB debugging on a phone](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)? Developing for Android is much more convenient, if you get the USB debugging working on a phone or tablet.

Comment: i added the error in the logcat @MarkusKauppinen

Comment: i added the error in the logcat @KevinRobatel

Comment: @MuhammedRamadan the logcat that you post is not linked to your app. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect your android phone to your computer. For that, you have to enable the developper mode in your smartphone. 
Then i should works :)